# Why I obtain this RuntimeException when I try to set a different content view into the onCreate() method of my activity?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I am absolutly new in Android development and I have the following problem.

I have a **MainActivity** class that contains this **onCreate()** method that is performed at the startup of my application:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);

    // Instantiate the list of samples.
    mSamples = new Sample[] {
            new Sample(R.string.title_screen_slide, ScreenSlideActivity.class),

    };

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Sample>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            mSamples));
}
```

As you can see in the previous code snippet currently it is performed at the startup application and show the **layout.activity_main** layout that is defined into the **res/layout/layout.activity_main.xml** file, that only contain this code:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" />
```

So, I tryed to modify the previous method in order that is shown another view. So basically I replaced this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

whith this one:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);
```

that set the **res/layout/layout.activity_screen_slide.xml** view, that only contains a **ViewPager** element, this one:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The problem is that now when this line is performed:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);
```

I obtain this exception:

```
06-11 17:43:58.167 28738-28738/com.example.android.animationsdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.android.animationsdemo, PID: 28738
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.animationsdemo/com.example.android.animationsdemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
         Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
            at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:408)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2156)
            at com.example.android.animationsdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Why? How is it possible? The **ListView** element is declared inside the first **layout.activity_main** that is replaced by this instruction:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);
```

Why I obtain this exception? What am I missing? How can I try to solve this issue?

Comment: As you said the ListView element is declared inside the first layout.activity_main but not in layout.activity_screen_slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your MainActivity inherits from `ListActivity` because you are using the method `setListAdapter`.

If you don't want to use a `ListView` then you can inherit from `Activity`.

But if you want to continue using a `ListView` then add it to `layout.activity_screen_slide`.

Answer (score 4):

Your content layout must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'. That's a requirement for ListActivity.

If you want to have different content (other than ListView) then use Activity or AppCompatActivity instead of ListActivity.